# Problem integrating web3j into maven clean install

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project where I want to generate java wrappers from .sol files, to achieve this I'm using web3j's maven plugin. Here are the (relevant sections of the) poms:

main `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>web3j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

child `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>web3j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <soliditySourceFiles>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/solidity</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.sol</include>
                    </includes>
                </soliditySourceFiles>
                <packageName>org.example.project-name.wrappers</packageName>
                <outputDirectory>
                    <java>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/web3j/java</java>
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm build the project with maven with the following command: `call mvn clean -U install`.
The files do generate, and in the correct location, but when maven begins the compile phase of install it runs into the following error:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/source/project/project-name/src/main/java/org/example/child/TestFile.java:[4,51] 
package org.example.project-name.wrappers does not exist
```

`TestFile` is an empty file that tries to import one of the generated files.

I also have an `openapi` code generator plugin, it does generate files properly, and I run into no issues when importing those.
I didn't find any configuration options in the web3j plugin that I missed and I also didn't find any way to help `mvn install` or `mvn compile` consider the directory in which the wrappers are generated.

I tried manually extracting the bundled calls that install makes and manually interjecting the web3j:generate-sources:

```
 call mvn clean
 call mvn web3j:generate-sources
 call mvn process-resources
 call mvn compile
 call mvn process-test-resources
 call mvn test
 call mvn package
 call mvn install
 call mvn deploy
```

But this too fails at compile. I'm assuming that the web3j plugin doesn't update a variable storing all generated sources, but that's just a guess and I don't know how I would fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using org.codehaus:build-helper-maven-plugin.

I added the plugin to the dependencies of my main pom and the relevant child (I use dependency management), then added the plugin to the child's pom:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/web3j</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also figured out that my assumption was correct: web3j's plugin does not update the project's sources directory.